# How to bypass network errors while using Ruby Mechanize web crawling

Tags: ruby, web-crawler, mechanize, rescue

I am using the Ruby mechanize web crawler to pull data from popular real estate websites. I'm using the home address as keywords to scrape the public data on Zillow, Redfin, etc. 
I'm basically trying to bypass any HTTP and network errors. The following rescue function doesn't seem to do the job.

```
def scrape_single(key_word)
    #setup agent
    agent = Mechanize.new{ |agent|
        agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
    }
    agent.ignore_bad_chunking = true
    agent.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE 
    agent.request_headers = { "Accept-Encoding" => ""}
    agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
    agent.keep_alive = false

    #page setup
    begin
      agent.get(@@search_engine) do |page|
        @@search_result = page.form('f') do |search|
          search.q = key_word
        end.submit
      end 
    rescue Timeout::Error
      puts "Timeout"
      retry
    rescue Net::HTTPGatewayTimeOut => e
      if e.response_code == '504' || '502'
        e.skip
        sleep 5
      end
    rescue Net::HTTPBadGateway  => e
      if e.response_code == '504' || '502'
        e.skip
        sleep 5
      end
    rescue Net::HTTPNotFound => e
      if e.response_code == '404'
        e.skip
        sleep 5
      end
    rescue Net::HTTPFatalError => e
      if e.response_code == '503'
        e.skip
      end
    rescue Mechanize::ResponseCodeError => e
      if e.response_code == '404'
        e.skip
        sleep 5
      elsif e.response_code == '502'
        e.skip
        sleep 5
      else
        retry
      end
    rescue Errno::ETIMEDOUT
      retry
    end

    return @@search_result      # returns Mechanize::Page
  end
```

The following is an example of error message I get for a keyword with an address in MA.

> /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.1/gems/mechanize-2.7.5/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:323:in `fetch': 404 => Net::HTTPNotFound for https://www.redfin.com/MA/WASHINGTON/306-WERDEN-RD-Unknown/home/134059623 -- unhandled response (Mechanize::ResponseCodeError)

The actual message you see when you input the above URL is:

> Cannot GET /MA/WASHINGTON/306-WERDEN-RD-Unknown/home/134059623

My goal is to simply ignore and skip sporadic errors and move onto next keyword. I couldn't really find a working solution online and any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Honestly, any of those sites is going to start sending 403's after the first 50 or so requests so you've got much bigger problems than you think.

Comment: pguardiario  Do you think there is a way to just ignore the 403 and the like??

Comment: 403 means you've been blocked. What good would ignoring that do?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the error raised is **Mechanize::ResponseCodeError** and this is clearly a **404** response_code. But in your script you don't raise 404 response_code from **Mechanize::ResponseCodeError**

```
all_response_code = ['403', '404', '502']

rescue Mechanize::ResponseCodeError => e
  if all_response_code.include? response_code 
    e.skip
    sleep 5
  else
    retry
  end
```

Maybe if you add a condition for the 404 response_code, it will do the trick

**EDIT**
I changed the code a little bit in order to have less lines

Comment: Makushimaru I really appreciate your feedback. The shortened version definitely looks much better. I actually do have 404 rescue for `Mechanize::ResponseCodeError`. I truncated the original code and forgot to add it in. Somehow it never was successful in skipping the errors. `e.skip` wasn't actually doing what I had expected it to do.